# Change cursor to custom on rollover

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a graphics in my flash object and I want to change the cursor at rollover on this graphics . Here is my code as follows:

```
   on (rollOver) {
       Mouse.hide();
       startDrag(DynmcCrsr, true);
   }

   on (rollOut) {
       startDrag(DynmcCrsr, false);
       Mouse.show();
   }
```

The code work at rollover but not functioning at rollout. The cursor remains unaltered at rollout. I am new in action-script. So any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `stopDrag()`:

```
on (rollOut) {
   stopDrag();
   Mouse.show();
}
```

`Startdrag` has 1 required parameter and 5 optional parameters.
The first being the object you want to drag and the second one is `lockCenter`. So if you use `startDrag(object,false)` it will not stop dragging.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7f93.html